# Azure AKS user nodepool VM temporary storage requirements

Tags: azure, aks

Do AKS user nodepool VMs use Azure VM temporary storage for any purpose?

Can an AKS user nodepool run on VMs without temporary storage?

What is is the minimal amount of Azure VM temporary storage required to run an AKS user nodepool VM?

We're not planning to use ephemeral OS disks.

Cannot find the answer in the MS docs.

Comment: Could you find any infos about this?